# How to access a dynamically generated property in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

For the below code, I register the TextField name as `M1.${index}.M13-M14` and it is required. However, the error is not able to be generated since it is not able to locate the property accessor via `` errors[`M1.${index}.M13-M14`]?.type ``. How am I able to access the errors if the value that is passed is dynamically generated like `M1.${index}.M13-M14`? What will the proper syntax be?

```
<TextField
   {...register(`M1.${index}.M13-M14`, { required: true })}
   fullWidth
   error={errors[`M1.${index}.M13-M14`]?.type === 'required'}
/>
```

Comment: How do you know it's specifically the dynamic name that is causing issues for you? Please take the [tour], read [ask] and how to make a [mre], then edit you question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `get` function from `lodash` that can access a *nested* value based on a string key.

```
import { get } from 'lodash';

error={get(errors, `M1.${index}.M13-M14`)?.type === 'required'}
```

More information: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get

---

Or just do it manually:

```
errors['M1'][index]['M13-M14']
```

Comment: thank you, lodash worked however doing it manually like `errors['M1'][index]['M13-M14']` produced a syntax error, is there a different way to do it manually?

Comment: @user21476047 I guess you need to secure the case if the object is undefined. `errors['M1']?.[index]?.['M13-M14']`. Syntax is okey.